# Is there an `OrderedMapping` storage type available in ink?

Tags: ink, storage

I'm new to ink! smart contracts, and trying to figure out how to set up my storage. I have a basic DAO. The DAO has members, and each member has a score (a u128) associated. So far a mapping sounds like the perfect thing.

Occasionally we will need the members sorted by their scores. I'm curious if it is practical to keep the data sorted in storage.

Comment: Which type are the scores set to?

Comment: @forgetso The score is a u128. I edited that into the question.

Answer (score 0):

If the DAO set is not too large, it would be best to use a `BTreeMap`.

Currently there is no ordered mapping available even in the pallet, IIRC.

Comment: I do not have proof for that (I work on this) but my best guess is that BTreeMap is not the best one if the cost usage matters. For demo/proof of concept, I agree that BTreeMap could be probably the best one.